# Problem in replacing body contents with ajax from a django HttpResponse

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm using Django as server and trying to update contents in a body tag periodcally with ajax.
The ajax part looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>A Pyecharts Demo</title>
{% for jsfile_name in script_list %}
    <script src="{{ host }}/{{ jsfile_name }}.js"></script>
{% endfor %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
     url:"/first_pyecharts/",
     type:'POST',
     data:{ 'last_update':'{{ last_update }}', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
     dataType: "html",
     success: function (html) {
        document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = html
    }
});
}, 10000);
</script>

<body id="body"> 
<!-- contents to be replaced -->
</body>
```

related codes in views.py:

```
if last_update is None:
    update_context(cur)
    template = loader.get_template('pyecharts.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
elif latest > datetime.strptime(last_update, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'):
    update_context(cur)
    template = loader.get_template('pyecharts.body.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
else:
    template = loader.get_template('pyecharts.body.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

The server returns an HttpResponse with template either rendered by previously stored or new context based on 'last_update' submitted from ajax.

Here the template 'pyecharts.html' is the complete page with 'html', 'head', 'script' and 'body' parts as shown above. While 'pyecharts.body.html' only contains the contents within the 'body' part, which is used to update the 'body' tag inside the webpage.

But When ajax gets its response from Django, it seems to have replaced the whole page with the response, removing the rest tags of the webpage.

Can anyone please kindly tell me where I did improperly? Is it because template rendered with both context and request? Coz I found render method with context only from Django docs. I'm not sure.

Comment: script is not a separate part of the page and cannot stand on its own. It needs to be inside either head or body.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for the advice, I moved script part into head. But I think the script did work though it was seperately placed. Because it did send a POST request every 10 seconds. Now I'm suspecting that the javascripts from within the response were not executed properly, coz the response is almost formed by pyecharts generated javascripts.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to keep the dynamic content in a partial template.
Create a partial html file and keep the dynamic content there.

Using render_to_string(), send the data to the template like so

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def get_item(request):
    # your code
    if last_update is None:
        html = render_to_string('your_path_to_the_partial', {'context_variable': variable})
        return HttpResponse(html)
    .....
```

now receive the data in the template and put it inside #dynamic_content in the same way you did earlier using js.

```
<body>
    <div id="dynamic_content"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was trying to do. 'pyecharts.body.html' corresponds to   the partial part as you mensioned here. Is there a chance that the javascripts from within the response were not executed properly? The response here is mainly formed by pyecharts generated javascripts.